# Apexcharts: radar chart click event on xAxis label

Tags: apexcharts, radar-chart, ng-apexcharts

[SEE PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwdEm.png) I'm using apexcharts for displaying a radar chart. I want to trigger an event when the user clicks on one of the categories of the radar (see image), but the event doesn't seem to be triggered. I have read the documentation and used, between all the events, the **xAxisLabelClick** event, which seems to work for the other charts. Does anyone know how?

I have tried all the apexcharts [events](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/chart/events/), but none of the work

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it's a bug. I've just filled an [issue](https://github.com/apexcharts/apexcharts.js/issues/3584).